# Simpson rule integration. (Math/Chemistry)

Tags: integration

```
Do a Simpsons rule integration of:
ln(f/p)=Integral((C-1)/P)dp from 0 to P
```

After a long derivation with the van der Waals equation and an expansion...

> C = 1 + (1/(RT))*(b-(a/(RT))*P

```
a=18
b=0.01154
R=0.082057
T=300
P=0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 ,3 ,3.5 ,4 ,4.5 , 5
```

I'ts been a long time since I've taken all my calculus and I'm completly stuck on performing this simpons rule. I already calculated all the C's.

```
 C = {0.9856173341992643`, 0.9707658885666232`, 
 0.955914442933982`, 0.9410629973013408`, 0.9262115516686996`, 
 0.9113601060360584`, 0.8965086604034174`, 0.8816572147707762`, 
 0.866805769138135`, 0.8519543235054938`}
```

Thank you for all help/suggestions,

### Joe

The answers should be equal or very close too (I'm suppose to compare them):

```
f = P*(Exp[(b - (a/(R*T)])*(P/(R*T))

{0.00494492, 0.0197797, 0.0445043, 0.0791187, 0.123623, \
0.178017, 0.242301, 0.316475, 0.400538, 0.494492}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) just says the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ is about equal to $\frac 16(b-a)[f(a)+4f(\frac {a+b}2)+f(b)]$.  In your case, $a=0, b=P$, so you need $\frac {C(0)-1}P,\frac {C(\frac P2)-1}P,\frac {C(P)-1}P$ and plug them in.

Comment: So I tried to calculate for the first P=0.5=b

Using ((0.5-0)/6)*((C(0)−1)/P)+((C(P/2)−1)/P)+((C(P)−1)/P))

I got ln(f/p)= -0.001550815776
f=0.499225193059

and then I'm suppose to compare that answer to 0.00494492.
Did I calculate that correctly?
Thanks,
Joe